# I can't log in into a MAMP multi-installation

Tags: multi-sites, .htaccess

I know this is probably something super simple, but it's one of those days...

I have MAMP set up on my computer so that I can have several local Drupal installs. I have one in a folder called `d7` and another in `d6`. But I cannot log into either one for anything. I checked in the apache log and it says:

```
File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sites/default
```

Which is the wrong directory to check. It should be checking /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7/sites/default. Is this why I can't login? What should I change in .htaccess and/or httpd.conf?

EDIT My added vhosts is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@d7.example.com
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7"
   ServerName d7.example.com
   ErrorLog "logs/d7.example.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/d7.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also added the port under NameVirtualHost. I have changed the base path in Drupal's htaccess and the server never hits the right file. There's nothing there where it's looking. It needs to look inside d7 instead of htdocs.

EDIT 2

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
RewriteBase /d7
```

Comment: What's your vhosts config? And do you use Drupal's vanilla `.htaccess`? Is proper index.php executed or does it fail before hitting it?

Comment: "I have changed the base path in Drupal's htaccess" - please include that part of your `.htaccess` - it takes part in indentifying proper path